# What is there to do after beating the Elite Four/Champion (Post-Game)?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I've defeated the Elite Four and the Champion. The credits rolled and I've been teleported to my home in Vaniville Town. What is there to do now? Any specific events/features that are unlocked now?

I already know of and caught Mewtwo and Zyrgarde.

Comment: I'm sure the three legendary birds are roaming around the Kalos Region in X and Y.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other answers are pretty good, but just to add a couple more points.

- **Work on filling out your Pokedex**

  - Go back to different areas and catch Pokemon you're missing (check the Pokedex for their locations).
  - Trade between X & Y to [get the ones you can't catch in your game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134331/which-pokemon-do-i-need-to-trade-between-x-y-in-order-to-catch-em-all)
  - Evolve Pokemon you've caught already
  - I usually set up a Pokemon geared toward catching other Pokemon. Smeargle works well for this - Teach it *False Swipe*, *Mean Look*, a Paralysing move such as *Stun Spore*, and something else (I usually run with a move to hit Ghost Pokemon)
- **Try your hand at multiplayer**: Link battles tend to be a lot different to Singleplayer battles - they have their own tactics, and the battles tend to be harder as they're more evenly matched (where Singleplayer is geared towards you winning). You really have to focus on Team cohesion a lot more.

  - Check out [Smogon](http://www.smogon.com/) for different tactics, and check which Pokemon work well (and work well together). It's still geared toward Gen 5, as the community is still learning the ins and outs of X/Y, but most of the info there will stay relevant.
  - There's a big focus on having Pokemon with the right [Individual Values (IVs)](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Individual_values), [Effort Values (EVs)](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values) and [Natures](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nature). You can be average in multiplayer without worrying too much about these, but if you plan on entering tournaments this is where you'll gain the edge over your opponents.
- **[Trade for all the Vivillion variations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135850/vivillons-pattern-3ds-locations-who-do-i-need-to-trade-with/135851#135851)**: There are 18 different wing patterns, depending on which real-world Geographic area you hail from. See if you can trade for all types.

  - Most people on GTS will trade Scatterbug for Scatterbug, so this would be my first point of call.
  - Once you start looking for the harder to get ones, I'd check out some of the [forums](http://3dsforums.com/pok%E9mon-3ds-games-general-50/vivillon-mystery-wings-can-we-discover-hidden-secret-50131/)/[reddit](http://en.reddit.com/r/Vivillon) posts for people wanting to trade duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

After you beat the E4, you can go to Lumiose City, where Looker will send you a Holocast, asking you to come find him at the Looker Bureau. I can't tell you exactly where it is, but you can take a taxi there. It's under Facilities. Then you go through a small mini story with level 60-70 trainers.

Answer (score 4):

Later in Luminose City you get a mission from a private detective named 'Looker', who asks you to be his assistant.(And do some missions)

*He will not contact you until you have the upgraded Mega-Ring!*

To get the post game Mega Stones you need to upgrade your ring.

1. Go to *Kiloude City*
2. Enter the [Battle Maison](http://www.serebii.net/xy/battlemaison.shtml) until you get 1 win
3. Your rival will be standing at the benches at the top of the city
4. Beat him/her
5. You will get Absolite
6. The professor will give you a call.
7. Follow his instructions.

Comment: Maybe you could expand on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the one roaming legendary bird, depending on your starter will decide which bird is roaming. I had picked Fennekin for my starter so Zapdos is my legendary bird. But you have to encounter it 12 times before you can actually catch it. [This was taken from Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/legendary.shtml)

Did you get all the Mega Evolutions? That is another thing you can do. I ended up going through the elite four beefing up my O-Powers and gaining more experience. Saved up enough money to buy the Charizard and Venusaur mega stones (since I picked Squirtle originally), and then traded and bred for Charmander and Bulbasuar. [Mega Evolutions](http://www.serebii.net/xy/megaevolutions.shtml) some are ONLY available post game.

Also go to Kiloude City and go to the Friend Safari. But you need to have other Friend Code's and your friends playing to be able to access this. [Friend Safari](http://www.serebii.net/xy/friendsafari.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

you can do the looker mission,  if you don't know how to do it just look on serebii.net (may have spoilers!)
you also could evolve the pokemon you caught that aren't in your party or go catch some new pokemon C: also after you beat the elite 4 you should see that you can buy new clothing, if you bought the clothing in the pre-game on the post-game new clothing should be at the stores! At least that's what happened to me. You also could go look for the mega-stones that you could get at 8:00 am

Comment: I don't think this is correct; I'm pretty sure clothing simply changes every day (though it has a chance to be an item you've already purchased)