# Vivillon's Pattern 3DS Locations - Who do I need to trade with?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

According to [Vivillon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Vivillon_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29)'s Pokedex Entry, they have different wing patterns depending on their original location in the world:

> Vivillon with many different patterns are found all over the world. These patterns are affected by the climate of their habitat

So I've been doing some research, and it seems the pattern is determined by the **real-world** location of the 3DS in which [Scatterbug](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Scatterbug_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) was first caught, in some countries down to individual states/regions.

This seems to have exploded on [forums](http://3dsforums.com/pok%E9mon-3ds-games-general-50/vivillon-mystery-wings-can-we-discover-hidden-secret-50131/) and [Reddit](http://en.reddit.com/r/Vivillon), but as of yet I cannot find a definitive source of the possible variations, and their locations.

So, What are the locations I need to trade with in order to get all the different patterns?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are [18 confirmed](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/666.shtml) patterns, and there are people who've managed to Catch 'Em All. Here's a YouTube video that shows them all caught:

These are the locations I've managed to piece together from firsthand experience and digging all over the internet, including various forums, reddit & tumblr posts (linked below).

### Locations

1. **River**:

   - *Australia* (New South Wales and South Australia confirmed, although it seems all states are the same)
2. **Meadow**:

   - *Austria*
   - *Japan*
   - *France*
   - *Germany*
   - *Italy*
   - *Luxembourg*
   - *UK*
   - *US* (Oregon)
3. **Elegant**:

   - *Japan* (Hokkaido)
   - *USA*
4. **Modern**:

   - *USA* (Alabama, Arkansas, Delaware, Florida, Georgia, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisianna, Maryland, Minnesota, Missouri, Nebraska, Nevada, North Carolina, North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, South Carolina, Tennessee, Texas, Virginia, West Virginia)
   - *Canada* (Manitoba)
   - *Bulgaria*
5. **Polar**:

   - *Canada* (Alberta, New Brunswick, Ontario, Saskatchewan, Quebec, Nova Scotia)
   - *Sweden*
   - *Norway*
   - *USA* (Alaska, Conneticut, Maine, Massachusetts, Michigan, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New York, Rhode Island, Pennsylvania, Wisconsin, Wyoming)
6. **Garden**:

   - *UK*
   - *USA* (Virginia)
   - *Czech Republic*
   - Netherlands
   - *Ireland*
   - *Australia* (Tasmania)
   - *New Zealand*
   - *Poland*
7. **Marine**:

   - *Austria*
   - *Chile*
   - *France*
   - *Germany*
   - *Greece*
   - *Italy*
   - *Poland*
   - *Spain*
   - *Potugal*
   - *Greece*
8. **Continental**:

   - *Belgium*
   - *France*
   - *Germany*
   - *Korea*
   - *Poland*
   - *Russia*
   - *Netherlands*
   - *Norway*
   - *Sweden*
   - *Denmark*
   - USA (Colorado)
   - *Estonia*
9. **Tundra**:

   - *Norway*
   - *Iceland*
10. **Sun**:

    - *Mexico*
11. **Icy Snow**:

    - *Finland*
    - *Canada* (Yukon, Northwest Territories, Nunavut)
    - Norway
12. **High Plains**:

    - *USA* (Arizona, California, Oregon, Utah, Idaho, New Mexico, Washington Colorado)
    - *Canada* (British Columbia)
13. **Jungle**:

    - *Malaysia*
    - *Colombia*
    - *Singapore*
14. **Ocean**:

    - *USA* (Hawaii)
    - *Reunion* (Island off the coast of Madagascar)
15. **Savannah**

    - *Brazil*
    - *Peru*
16. **Sandstorm**

    - *United Arab Emirates*
    - *Somalia*
17. **Monsoon**

    - *Hong Kong*
    - *India*
    - *Japan*
18. **Archipelago**

    - *Puerto Rico*
    - *Saint Lucia*
    - *South Africa* (Western Cape)
    - *Arizona* (US)

### Notes

- There are a few duplicates, especially in the US states, so please comment or edit if you find other locations, or if a listed location is invalid.

  - It could be that you haven't set your State in the 3DS, so make sure that your State is set.
- Changing your 3DS location and catching Scatterbugs **doesn't work**. Apparently the game will only pick up your location at the start of the game, so you will need to restart if you want to change it.
- Breeding foreign Vivillion locally doesn't work either - the resulting Scatterbug still counts as being from your region

### Sources:

- [Serebii.net](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/666.shtml)
- [3DS forums](http://3dsforums.com/pok%E9mon-3ds-games-general-50/vivillon-mystery-wings-can-we-discover-hidden-secret-50131/)
- [r/Vivillon](http://en.reddit.com/r/Vivillon)
- [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67475414)
- [PokeBeach](http://www.pokebeach.com/forums/thread-vivillon-location-for-various-colours)
- [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10F8y.jpg)
- [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPKcPPfzjeA)
- [Project Pokemon](http://projectpokemon.org/forums/showthread.php?32865-Vivillon-Patterns)
- [Tumblr](http://31.media.tumblr.com/d580e956576b4a4fa2037706c51f79a5/tumblr_mul2x2emeq1rfnwv0o1_1280.png)
- [Another Tumblr](http://icyblueroses.tumblr.com/)

Comment: So all bred Vivillon are "natives", regardless of their parents?

Comment: @RavenDreamer - Yup. I've edited to make this clearer

Comment: @scenia The egg will hatch with the same pattern of the region it was created in, I.e. if someone sends you a meadow egg, it will be the Meadow pattern on your game when hatched and evolved