# How do I use the Battle Box?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I wanted to train up a few Scatterbug that I had [traded for](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135850/vivillons-pattern-3ds-locations-who-do-i-need-to-trade-with), so I put my regular team in the Battle Box, thinking that if I were challenged to a battle, I'd get to pick to use them instead.

So of course, I was challenged to a battle. I accepted, and when I got to the screen where I could pick which Pokemon are entered, I only saw what was currently in my party, and no option to get my Pokemon from the Battle Box.

Is this what the Battle Box is used for? Why couldn't I battle with the Pokemon in it?

Comment: The answer below it's wrong, you initially see only your party, but after a couple of screens you can choose your Battle Box, too.

Comment: @pinckerman - apparently not for random passerby battles, which is why I asked initially.

Comment: How is it possible? I battle only random passerby and I can choose my Battle Box.

Comment: No idea. Perhaps it was 'free battle' and I didn't have 6 Pokemon? It was over a year ago lol, I can't remember.

Comment: I don't know if you must have a full team, I doubt it. Probably you left the battle too early? I've figured out that you can choose the Battle Box only when I tried to go ahead with the process. The first screen is misleading.

Comment: No, I still battled with whatever was in my party (mainly because right up until the team preview screen I was waiting for it to prompt me).

Comment: Probably you did something wrong that we can't know. Anyway, I ensure you that you can use the Battle Box team in random online battles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The battle box can only be used in in infrared link battles, the Battle Subway, Random Matchup and Tournaments which utilize the "Battle Competition".

source: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Storage_System

Try doing a inferred link battle and see if you can use the battle box.

Comment: While this seems to be largely true... "Battle Subway" is something that was Gen5 (although the Gen6 equivalent Battle Maison does still offer battle box capabilities). That Bulbapedia page does not seem to be updated to current Generation 6 yet.

Comment: The Battle Box is also a convenient place to store your frequently switched-out Pokemon, as it is the first box and is presented first on the 'Deposit Pokemon' and 'Withdraw Pokemon' menus.